# Can I remove the subject, as in "It's helpful as removes pain"?

Tags: ellipsis, subjects

Can subject in subordinated clause be omitted if it's same as in main clause even if verb isn't be-copular? E.g.:

> It's helpful as removes pain.

Comment: I can't understand what your asking, but your specific example is definitely not grammatical.

Answer (score 7):

No, the subject can't be removed, but you can use a pronoun instead of repeating the subject noun. For example:

> Aspirin is helpful, as it removes pain.

Comment: I've seen lines "It's alright
As long as kills the pain" in the song "Comfortable Place". Isn't it used correctly? Cuz there is elipsis of subject in line "As long as kills the pain"

Comment: It is NOT used correctly in the song. It should be "as long as it kills the pain"

Comment: Song lyrics often use incorrect grammar to match the beat or emphasize key words, or for other reasons. They are usually not good models of or evidence for proper usage.